# Upgrading php in Linux

Tags: php, linux

I am running a Redhat on a webserver. The current version of php on the server is 5.1.6. I want to upgrade it to 5.3.8 so I downloaded php and compiled it and replaced the older php binary with the newer one. I then restarted the httpd daemon. When I type `php -v` on the command line it gives me 5.3.8 but when I look at php on the browser using `<?phpinfo();?>` I get 5.1.6. How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably using Apache together with mod_php5, which is outdated.

Comment: So I need to upgrade mod_php5 separately?

Comment: Can you output the contents of your PATH variable?

Comment: You might want to post this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or serverfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about official way?

```
yum update php php-* -y
```

Never ever mess up system with downloading tar/gz while official package exists.

Also look here : http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-centos-5.3-lamp

Be sure to restart apache after upgrade :

```
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and compile the PHP *module*, not the PHP command line binary. So you will also need to recompile (a part of) Apache httpd. Which also mean recompiling (a part of) SSL if you use HTTPS.

But doesn't Red Hat come with a package upgrade capability? Why do you need to recompile everything?

Comment: You don;t need to download/compile apache's module.YUM package php also provides mod_php.

Answer (score 0):

Many of us use the [remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/) to keep current with PHP and MySQL. It will currently give you PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5 on EL5 and EL6. All you need to do is install the `remi-release` RPM and then `yum upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the atomic repo in order to updated your PHP, used it many times and it works like a charm, here is a link http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/PHP